# How to timeout an AlertDialog in Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How can i handle timeout in an alertdialog. It has the standard yes/no button but i want to call the no button code if the user doesn't press anything in 5 minutes.
I've looked at the class in Android page and there's no function which can be called to set a timeout.

Comment: Do you mean an AlertDialog which auto dismiss in a certain time?

Comment: use a Handler with postDelayed() or sendMessageDelayed()

Comment: @iStar yes. with a yes/no button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example, hope be helpful.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static final int TIME_OUT = 5000;

    static final int MSG_DISMISS_DIALOG = 0;

    private AlertDialog mAlertDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createDialog();
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_DISMISS_DIALOG:
                if (mAlertDialog != null && mAlertDialog.isShowing()) {
                    mAlertDialog.dismiss();
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    private void createDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null)
            .setNegativeButton("cacel", null);
        mAlertDialog = builder.create();
        mAlertDialog.show();
        // dismiss dialog in TIME_OUT ms
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_DISMISS_DIALOG, TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Comment: i already have a dialogclicklistener which reacts to yes and no. this handler is in addition to that? or do i need to modify the approach to use handler instead of dialogclicklistener?

Comment: @NaveenSharma yes, this handler is a field of your `Activity`, has nothing to do with dialogclicklistener. Just keep your dialogclicklistener.

Answer (score 10):

I have used a Dialog for achieving this instead of using the alert dialog.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        yourDialogObj.dismiss();
    }
}, 2000);
```

here 2000 is miliseconds,

Hope this helps